# how to make last row of datagrid in WPF readonly

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid which is editable where in there are  columns with months and few rows which change based on search criteria.Numbers can be entered in these cells,the total of these numbers is added in the last row and calculated by me in CellEditEnding event .However the last row of Total is also editable which shouldnt be allowed ,is there a way to make only last row read only.

There is propety to make DataGrid readonly and also column read only but there is no property to make only specific row readonly.

I tried the below code from a post

```
private void dataGrid_LoadingRow_1(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.IsNewItem)
            e.Row.IsEnabled = true;
        else
            e.Row.IsEnabled =false;
    }
```

but this doesnt work .

I tried getting data grid row

```
DataGridRow lastRow = this.dataGrid.Items[rowCount - 1];

   
    lastRow.IsReadOnly = true;
```

but the DataGridRow doesnt have any IsReadOnly attribute

Answer (score 0):

found the solution ,have to use BeginningEdit event

```
 private void WdgModelwiseForecast_BeginningEdit(object sender, DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.Item == wdgModelwiseForecast.Items[wdgModelwiseForecast.Items.Count - 1])
            {
                // Cancel the edit operation for the last row
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
```